# Array List Printing three times when only one file is in it

Tags: vb.net, winforms

The following functions loads files of ssh directory and populates a list view with the files for the users to select to download but for some reason its populating the list three times the array list gets split up into three segments with the (2) part being the filename why is it not just adding one element to the listview here thanks

```
 Private Sub LoadSSHFiles()      
    Dim sshController As New wcSFtp(cfb.HostName, cfb.port, cfb.username, cfb.passsword)
    Dim thisDocument As ArrayList = sshController.getDirectoryList("/")

    Dim cnt As Int16 = 0

    For Each item In thisDocument(2)

        Dim lvItem As New ListViewItem(cnt)
        lvItem.SubItems.Add(thisDocument(2).ToString())
        lvAvailableDocuments.Items.Add(lvItem)
        cnt += 1

    Next
```

Comment: maybe `LoadSSHFiles` is getting called three times.  set a breakpoint to see that is what happens

Comment: @Plutonix no its only getting called on the form load :-(

Comment: @Plutonix i see whats going on now its thinking each chrachter is a element to be adding of the file name?

Comment: turn on Option Strict. I am not sure what sshController is or does, but it either returns a list of files in which case your For/Each is just iterating one file N times, OR it parses a single file into name parts in which case, you are still iterating one part N times.  I cant see anything about an Arraylist getting "split up into parts" - that would have to result in some new data structure

Comment: `ArrayList`s are old and should not be used anymore. We have betters things to use like `Generics`.

Comment: Use item.ToString() instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
' this line iterates thru the members of ONE element of
' the ArrayList.  If you are adding strings to the
' AL then you are iterating characters. Item is not Typed either
For Each item In thisDocument(2)

    this is creating a new array of LVI each time
    Dim lvItem As New ListViewItem(cnt)

    ' this adds the same thing to the LV 
    ' for each loop iteration
    lvItem.SubItems.Add(thisDocument(2).ToString())
    lvAvailableDocuments.Items.Add(lvItem)
    cnt += 1

Next
```

See the notes added above.  Usually when you iterate something, you do something with the index var; you are iterating one thing and adding that thing over and over.  With an ArrayList, you can use the count more easily:

```
Dim lvi As ListViewitem

' go thru the list
For n As Integer = 0 to thisDocument.Count - 1
     lvi = new ListViewItem
     lvi.Text = thisDocument(n)
     ' or, since there are no subitems:
     ' lvi = New ListViewItem(thisDocument(n))

     lvAvailableDocuments.Items.Add(lvi)
Next n
```

Now, all you have to do is properly see that `thisDocument` is properly seeded with teh files you want.